# Azure SQL database newly created table does not allow to insert data but all old tables allow insert data

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

my azure sqldatabase old table are work proper when i insert or get data , but my requirement is new table create and insert data , i create new table using azure studio , table create successfully but i can't insert data on that table when i insert data i got error Like this :

> ▿ Optional
>
> - some : Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "Cannot POST /tables/QOWResult "
>   UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse:
>   0x60000031eea0> { URL: https://myurl/tables/QOWResult } { Status Code:
>   404, Headers {
>   "Content-Length" =     (
>   30
>   );
>   "Content-Type" =     (
>   "text/html; charset=utf-8"
>   );
>   Date =     (
>   "Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:32:54 GMT"
>   );
>   Server =     (
>   "Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
>   );
>   "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
>   nosniff
>   );
>   "X-Powered-By" =     (
>   Express,
>   "ASP.NET"
>   ); } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot POST /tables/QOWResult , com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest:
>   0x6000001d30c0> { URL: https://myurl/tables/QOWResult }}

i try create new table with azure portal too but when i insert table data on it , get error above , also i share my code of insert data.

```
static func addOneWayResult( item: [String: Any],  handler: @escaping(QwizzOnewayResult?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let table = client?.table(withName: "QOWResult")
    table?.insert(item) { (insertedItem, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            handler(nil, error)
            return
        }
        handler(QwizzOnewayResult(JSON(insertedItem!)),nil)
    }
}
```

This are my column name of that table :-

> [Senderid] nvarchar NOT NULL, [Sendername] nvarchar NOT
> NULL, [SenderAvtar] nvarchar NOT NULL, [Reciever_id]
> nvarchar NOT NULL, [Recievername] nvarchar NOT NULL,
> [RecieverAvtar] nvarchar NOT NULL, [GameID] nvarchar NOT
> NULL, [Gamename] nvarchar NOT NULL, [WinnerName]
> nvarchar NOT NULL, [InTime] nvarchar NULL,
> [AttempCounter] nvarchar NOT NULL, [create_date] [datetime] NOT
> NULL

[image: Here is the old and new table list from studio]

Comment: I don't know anything about azure but the http response is 404, page not found, so maybe start there. Maybe a spelling or configuration error somewhere.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i checked double time with old configuration, actually application have already existing table , so for create new table we have just follow the structure , and i did this but , i got error when i m insert data on that table, Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: Well it's clear to me that the endpoint for the table can't be found

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes that's right but why this happen ? coz old all table work proper insert data as well as get data , only problem with newly created tables , and also i tried 
create another table and same error get !! i really don't understand why this happen for new table. and i know that table can't be found , actually table is there with old tables.

Comment: i update question with showing table list with new created table

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong place since you insist on talking about the tables themselves but I believe this is about some configuration concerning how they are published in the API or similar or maybe some access/privileges configuration. Anyway, this (azure) is not my area as I mentioned so I will leave this discussion now.

Comment: @JayBhalani which account did you use to connect to the Azure SQL database, can you try the database admin account? It seams that you have the permission to query but can't create and update permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation

- Insert into old tables works
- Insert into new table returns a 404
- All tables in same database

Based on this it is probably a rights issue.

The connection to the database is done in a context of a user. If that user does not have access to the table, it will return a 404 not found error.

You need to grant user rights on the new table.